# cannot retrieve object from generic type in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-contenttypes

I am trying to retrieve a generic object like so:

```
generic_type = ContentType.objects.get(app_label="customers", model="Customer")
print generic_type.id 
print 'customer: '+str(customer.id)
setting = generic_type.get_object_for_this_type(object_id=customer.id)
```

Both print statements spit out the proper values stored in my database.

I am following the retrieval as found in the docs here:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType

I am running django 1.4.3

Is there anything wrong with my retrieval method?

Comment: When you use Django 1.4 then you should use the docs for Django 1.4, not the latest development docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/

Comment: they are the same in this instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with the following:

```
generic_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(customer)
setting = Preference.objects.filter(content_type__pk=generic_type.id, object_id=customer.id)
```